# Activate wireless on a headless Ubuntu box via ssh

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, ssh, remote

Okay, so I have an interesting setup going on.

Far away from me, is a headless (no monitor) Ubuntu box hooked up to an ethernet cable.
This computer is intended to be a public internet station at a hostel, it's just waitinig for me to finish the wifi configuration, and then the owner will put it in place, hook up a monitor, and that's it.

The computer HAS a wireless card, which seems to work (i.e., I can give it commands through iwlist).

1. I have ssh access with X forwarding enabled.
2. When I log in, and run `ps -e | grep nm-applet` I see it isn't running.
3. I checked `gnome-session-properties` and nm-applet is listed there to start.

So my questions are:

What can I do to get nm-applet running? Maybe it's running and I can't see it?
Otherwise, what can I do to set it to connect to WiFi automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use iwconfig. Here's a [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WiFiHowTo).

Answer (score 0):

Well if its a wpa secured wireless network, you would probably start up wpa_supplicant, and then dhclient. you could prolly set up the box to start it at each reboot. there's NO reason to use nmapplet on a headless box

On one of my boxes, i have a script that starts both, - the commands for wpa_supplicant vary depending on the box, and you would need to set up a conf file, but this is the most straightforward way to do it.

[this question might help](https://superuser.com/questions/90970/running-a-connection-script-on-boot-on-ubuntu-or-using-etc-networks-properly) - its solutions to a similar issue

Comment: ah, but it's not meant to be a headless box. As soon as it's on the wireless, it will be moved to another room, and have a monitor attached.

Comment: if you don't need to roam, or its a cli box, its still the most straightwardward way. if you're running gnome, or kde, then well go for the nmapplet method

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have managed to setup wifi for my slackware and [blogged about it](http://phunehehe.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/wireless-networking-in-slackware/)
In short, at the point that all the settings seemed to be done (while I still cannot connect), I just needed a command

```
dhcpcd wlan0
```

Hope that can help

Comment: Do you mean dhclient? That's not working.
`iwconfig` tells me I'm on the network, but no IP address.

Comment: you can look at my question here http://superuser.com/questions/84622/setup-wireless-networking-on-slackware  
it's dhcpcd, not dhclient, don't you have it?

Comment: I don't have dhcpd running on the ubuntu box, because it's supposed to acquire an address, not assign it.